# django-smart-selects update only chained but not foreignkey

Tags: python, django

When in forms.py i show the form to the user. Departamentos dropdown shows all of the departamentos instead of the ones that belong to a specific empresa example.

What i mean is that by using this Query it shows all the departamentos from the table instead from where it belongs. how come? if I'm sending the 2 ID values to make specific the query

id= Current User ID

empresa = Current Company ID Where User Belongs

[image]

```
empleadoObject = empleado.objects.get(
                    id=request.session['member_id'], 
                    empresa=request.session['company_id'])

                form = UpdateEmpleadoForm(
                    request.POST, instance=empleadoObject)

                form = UpdateEmpleadoForm(instance=empleadoObject)
```

models.py

```
class empresa(models.Model):

codigo = models.CharField(max_length=11)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
logo = StdImageField(upload_to='logo/%Y/%m/%d', variations={
    'large': (300, 300),
    'thumbnail': (280, 55, True)})
correo = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=21)
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
usuario = models.CharField(max_length=15)
password = models.CharField(max_length=40)

def logoEmpresa(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s" height="90" width="90">' % (self.logo.thumbnail)

logoEmpresa.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class departamento(models.Model):

empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class empleado(models.Model):

empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)

GENDER_CHOICES = (

    ('M', 'Masculino'),
    ('F', 'Femenino'),
)

sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

avatar = StdImageField(upload_to='avatar/%Y/%m/%d', variations={
    'large': (300, 300, True),
    'medium': (50, 50, True),
    'thumbnail': (98, 122, True)})

correo = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

departamento = models.ForeignKey(departamento)

telefono = models.CharField(max_length=21)
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
twitter = models.CharField(max_length=15)
usuario = models.CharField(max_length=15)
password = models.CharField(max_length=40)
primer_lugar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
segundo_lugar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
tercer_lugar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
goleador = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def avatarEmpleado(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s" height="90" width="90">' % (self.avatar.thumbnail)

avatarEmpleado.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand you right. if you want to make a query with attribute of a foreign key you should use __attribute

```
empleadoObject = empleado.objects.get(
                id=request.session['member_id'], 
                empresa__id=request.session['company_id'])
```

with empresa__id you access to a object atribute even if they are not a foreign key. Try with that.

Comment: What i mean is  empleado has many departamentos (empresa "company in english) (departamentos "Departments in english") so company has many departments. but i need to call all the departments from that company on that specific user. instead of getting all the items from all departments without filtering them by companyid

Comment: but you are doing a get(), get() just return one match, if you want all the departments you have to use filter. And in your model you have that empleado has just one departamento and one empresa.

    departamento = models.ForeignKey(departamento)

I think is better if you create a middle model with 3 values. Empleado, empresa and departamento. With foreing Key in each field. In this way you have easy querys for what you want.

Comment: the  form should only show the departments from the company that is associated with instead of all of them i just need 1 profile to be edited. but it to show only the departments belongs to the company he is in not all of the departments from all companies.